# Deploying C# application with .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks, installation

If the end user dont have .net 4.0 installed , i dont want them to go to a microsoft page to download manually and install it. I rather want them to just click "ok" and the setup goes to my website and downloads the webinstaller file and start installing automatically.

In my solution i have 2 project, 1 windows project and 1 setup project. I have noticed that if i go to properties on either of the projects and then Prerequisites, there i can choose between these 3 options :

```
Download prerequisites from the component vendor's website ( default )
Download prerequisites from the same location as my application
Download prerequisites from the following location ( with a textbox )
```

I should want the last option right? But do i link to a folder in my website and it will look there for the right "name" to install ? Then i have to add the installers to that folder?

And i dont know if i only should do this on the windows project or the setup project or both?

I am using visual studios default installer.

Really confused.

Thanky you.

Comment: Which installer are you using? The default that comes with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i use the default installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is ok for you to distribute the .NET framework with the program you can use the instructions from the answer to this post:

[silent .NET Framework install in setup project](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/netfxsetup/thread/ed16357b-f7a9-4c17-a22c-edfadb045ec9)

The setup should install the .NET framework without requiring any user input.

Comment: I think technically this solution should work by specifying "Download prerequisites from the following location" targeting the setup on your site instead and following the rest of the steps shown there.

Answer (score 0):

I normally choose the second options.

- Why? Because VS actually compiles a bootstrapper which gets sent to you Debug/Release folder. So all you need to do is copy that whole folder and burn to cd or usb and ship to your client.

Comment: But dont i have to include the install files for .net 4.0 to my setup project output when choosing option 2 ?

Comment: If you tick them in the Prerequisites, they automatically get built to your output directory. EG you Debug folder. So you will have you Setup.msi, ProjectName.msi, and other folders like .Net4, Windows installer 3.1 etc

Comment: Option 2 isnt really good for me, because the user will only download the setup.exe file. This option is good if the user gets my setup in a cd/usb , in a directory with the other installers.

Comment: Then go with options 1, as the user will be re-directed to the vendors site and will get the latest and patched requirements.

Comment: Thats the whole purpose of this question.....i dont want the user to go to the vendors site and manually download it, i want the setup to do it automatically.

Comment: @syncis, then go with option 3, and specify the location to your website where the prerequisites are hosted.